# Identify connected subnetworks, constrained by edge attributes

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis, igraph, network-analysis

I am working with network data and want to identify connected subnetworks. I loaded my data using
`graph <- graph_from_data_frame(filtered_df, directed = FALSE)`
and ploted my network

`plot(graph)`

```
E(graph)$conflict_period
[1] "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "72_1"   "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1" 
[15] "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1"  "372_1"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0" 
[29] "522_0"  "522_0"  "522_0"  "715_0"  "715_0"  "715_0"  "715_0"  "5390_0"
```

So far, the information on the subgroups is stored in the edges. A Node belonges to each subgroup it receives an edge from, so a Node can also belong to multiple subgroups.For instance Government of Mali belongs together with Civilians to subgroups "72_1" and togehther with FIAA to subgroup "372_1". I want to know if subgroups "72_1" and "372_1" are conected, which they are if at least two Nodes belonging to subgroup "72_1" are conected via edges to at least two Nodes belonging to subgroup"372_1". I tired ways outside Network analysis to identify this relationship, but failed. Now I am here asking for help.

[image]

the desired output would be a table listing the connected subgroup based on the aforementioned criterium. In this case it should be:

| conflict_period | connected |
| --- | --- |
| 72_1 | 372_1,522_0 |
| 372_1 | 72_1,522_0 |
| 522_0 | 372_1,72_1 |
| 715_0 | NA |
| 5390_0 | NA |

Here is the used data:

```
structure(list(side_a = c("Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", 
"FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "MPGK", "MPGK", "MPGK", 
"MPGK", "ARLA, FIAA, FPLA"), side_b = c("Civilians", "Civilians", 
"Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", 
"Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "FIAA", "FIAA", 
"FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", 
"Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", 
"Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", 
"Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "MPA"), country = c("Mali", 
"Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", 
"Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", 
"Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", 
"Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", 
"Mali", "Mali", "Mali"), period_start = structure(c(765158400, 
765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 
765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 770256000, 770256000, 
770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 
770256000, 770256000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 
771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 
769910400, 769910400, 769910400, 769910400, 771206400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), period_end = structure(c(817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 
817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 
817862400, 817862400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 
819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 
816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 
816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 814492800, 814492800, 
814492800, 814492800, 802828800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), conflict_period = c("72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", 
"72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "372_1", 
"372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", 
"372_1", "372_1", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", 
"522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "715_0", "715_0", 
"715_0", "715_0", "5390_0")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. See the edit.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: why `715_0` has `NA` in `connected`?

Comment: 715_0 is the connection between Civilians and MPGK. There are no further nodes involved, so it misses the criterium that subgroups are only connect if there are edges between at least two nodes from each subgroup. It would be included if the was an edge between MPGK and FIAA and/or Government of Mali.

Comment: @KC15 I provided another solution and hope it is the thing you are after

Comment: The description is not very clear. Please show a concrete example input, and the expected output. Ideally, illustrate it visually. Try to describe what you are after using mathematically precise terms.

Comment: Is it possible to have more then one conflict name (f.e. 72_1, 372_1) between two vertices? Is it possible that the same conflict name occurs between different vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your latest update, here is one option to achieve your desired output

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

# simplify the dataframe and generate a graph
g <- df %>%
    select(matches("^side|conflict")) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)

# repeat pruning the graph and retaining the subgraph(s) such that each node has the degree >= 2
gh <- g
repeat {
    d <- degree(gh)
    if (min(d) >= 2) break
    gh <- induced_subgraph(gh, V(gh)[d >= 2])
}

# retrieve the vertices of each desired cluster
clt <- lapply(decompose(gh), \(x) E(x)$conflict_period)

# go through each conflict_period and if they are in one of the found clusters
out <- sapply(
    E(g)$conflict_period,
    \(p) {
        lapply(clt, \(q) {
            if (p %in% q) {
                setdiff(q, p)
            } else {
                NA
            }
        })
    }
)

# produce the desired output
res <- within(
    data.frame(conflict_period = names(out)),
    connected <- out
)
```

such that

```
> res
  conflict_period    connected
1            72_1 372_1, 522_0
2           372_1  72_1, 522_0
3           522_0  372_1, 72_1
4           715_0           NA
5          5390_0           NA
```

Comment: Would you please list the the libraries that are used. Function distinct() is not in R base.

Comment: @clp aha, sorry that I forgot to add the libraries. It is in `dplyr`

Comment: The code works for single cases, but when I tried to loop it for the entire dataset ``` out <- sapply(E(g)$conflict_period,
  \(p) {
    lapply(clt, \(q) {
      if (p %in% q) {
        setdiff(q, p)
      } else {
        NA
      }
    })
  }
)

# produce the desired output
res <- within(
  data.frame(conflict_period = names(out)),
  connected <- out
)

res
``` became an issue.

Comment: @KC15 what is your issue?

Comment: I placed a for loop in front of your solution. The loop has issues with "res <- within(
  data.frame(conflict_period = names(out)),
  connected <- out"  and the error is `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(connected = list(NA,  : 
  Ersetzungselement 1 ist Matrix/Dataframe mit 8 Zeilen, benötigt werden 0

Comment: @KC15 can you try `data.frame(conflict_period = names(out)) %>% mutate(connected = out)`?

Comment: I placed my loop under the data in the question, so you can have a look at it.

Comment: @KC15 I suggest you open a new question. There should be only one focus in each question, otherwise the community will vote to close your question if you have more than one focuses in a single topic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78088644/issue-when-looping-matrix-array-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should use `decompose` to separate the subgraphs and then retrieve the "subgroup" information in edges, e.g.,

```
df %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    decompose() %>%
    map(\(x) unique(E(x)$conflict_period))
```

which outputs

```
[[1]]
[1] "72_1"  "372_1" "522_0" "715_0"

[[2]]
[1] "5390_0"
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution however does not account for the criterium that subgroups are only connect if there are edges between at least two nodes from each subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `igraph::groups()` to find the connected clusters/subnetworks:

```r
filtered_df <- structure(list(side_a = c(
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali",
  "Government of Mali", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA",
  "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "MPGK", "MPGK", "MPGK",
  "MPGK", "ARLA, FIAA, FPLA"
), side_b = c(
  "Civilians", "Civilians",
  "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians",
  "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "FIAA", "FIAA",
  "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA", "FIAA",
  "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians",
  "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians",
  "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "Civilians", "MPA"
), country = c(
  "Mali",
  "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali",
  "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali",
  "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali",
  "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali", "Mali",
  "Mali", "Mali", "Mali"
), period_start = structure(c(
  765158400,
  765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400,
  765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 765158400, 770256000, 770256000,
  770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000, 770256000,
  770256000, 770256000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000,
  771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000, 771552000,
  769910400, 769910400, 769910400, 769910400, 771206400
), tzone = "UTC", class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
)), period_end = structure(c(
  817862400, 817862400, 817862400,
  817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400, 817862400,
  817862400, 817862400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400,
  819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400, 819158400,
  816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200,
  816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 816739200, 814492800, 814492800,
  814492800, 814492800, 802828800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
)), conflict_period = c(
  "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1",
  "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "72_1", "372_1",
  "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1", "372_1",
  "372_1", "372_1", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0",
  "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "522_0", "715_0", "715_0",
  "715_0", "715_0", "5390_0"
)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))

graph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(filtered_df, directed = FALSE)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

```r
graph |>
  igraph::cluster_optimal() |>
  igraph::groups()
#> $`1`
#> [1] "Government of Mali" "FIAA"               "MPGK"              
#> [4] "Civilians"         
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "ARLA, FIAA, FPLA" "MPA"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think OP wants to know the clusters of  the edge attribute `conflict_period`, instead of vertex clusters.

Comment: `cluster_optimal()` is a function for community detection. It maximizes modulairty exactly, which is NP-hard. Thus this function is extremely slow and only for on the smallest graphs. What OP is asking for is simply finding connected components, which is achieved by `components()` or `decompose()`. `groups()` doesn't really compute anything, it just transform a representation of clusters from one form to another.

Comment: Thank you. This solution however does not account for the criterium that subgroups are only connect if there are edges between at least two nodes from each subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

**Employing cliques**

```
                                                    # Sanitize input.
se <- E(graph)[which(count_multiple(graph) == 1)]   # Single edge.
# [1] "5390_0"
se$conflict_period                                  # Show. deletedconflicts
g2 <- delete_edges(graph, se)                       # Keep multiple edges.
g3 <- delete.vertices(g2, which(degree(g2)==0))     # Remove isolates.
g4 <- simplify(g3, edge.attr.comb = "first")        # Remove multiple edges.
E(g4)$label <- E(g4)$conflict_period                # Show edge label in plot().
plot(g4)
```

[image]

Observe that any 3-cycle a, b, c induces:

```
conflict_period  | connected
a                | b, c
b                | a, c
c                | a,b
```

In this small example we can read the solution directly from the graph.

```
                                            # show cliques.
cq  <- max_cliques(g4, min = 2, max=3)      # Find all 2,3-cycles.
tri <- list()                               # create a list of all cycles.
for (v in cq) tri[[length(tri)+1]] <- E(subgraph(g4, v))$conflict_period
tri
## [[1]]
## [1] "715_0"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "372_1" "72_1"  "522_0"
```